# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have problem when Deserialization Json in C#,

This my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private void JSONDeserilaize()
{
        string json = @"{""content"":[{""Number"":""3212012909920002""}],""size"":""1""}";

        Header empObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Header>(json);

        Response.Write(empObj.Data);
}
```

This is the output object interface

```
 public class Header
    {
        public string content { get; set; }
        public Content[] Data { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public string Number{ get; set; }
    }
```

Anybody can improve my code, please..

Comment: if it is  solved you better mark the answer with the green tick, assuming there is an answer that solved your issue. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong when declares Header class. Here is the solution. Hope to help, my friend :d

```
    public class Header
    {        
        public string size { get; set; }
        public Content[] content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string json = @"{""content"":[{""Number"":""3212012909920002""}],""size"":""1""}";
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            Header obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Header>(json);
            foreach(var item in obj.content)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Number);
            }

   }
```